# MacBook Pro: 2017 Unable to connect to Dell U2713HM with USB-C to DisplayPort cable

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos, usb, displayport

I am trying to connect my MBP 2017 to a Dell U2713HM with a [USB-C to DisplayPort cable (Part No ELUCDP-01)](https://www.alogic.co/alogic-usb-c-to-displayport-cable-with-4k-support-male-to-male-elements-series-1m.html) made by [Alogic](https://www.alogic.co/).

When I plug in the cable to the USB-C port, the monitor will say there is 'No DisplayPort cable' and then show 'Entering power saving mode'.

The main monitor on the other hand will dim for a moment and the keyboard will become unresponsive for a moment.

Anyone know how I can fix the issue?

Error messages in log:

[image]

```
ColorSync: ColorSyncProfileCreateWithDisplayID failed to get profile for kColorSyncDisplayDeviceClass
```

It seems to me the monitor can be recognised by the MBP. Here is a screenshot of ColorSync:

[image]

Comment: The cable might be bad. Have you tried connecting the cable to the USB port first, then to the monitor? What happens when you power everything down, connect the usb cable, then power everything up, starting with the monitor first, then the MBP?

Comment: It is purely a software issue. Please see my answer.

Comment: It still could be a cable issue - the clock sync of the DP signals could be the issue you are seeing.  Which cable do you have?  That company makes *many*.

Comment: 1m usb-c to displayport https://www.alogic.co/alogic-usb-c-to-displayport-cable-with-4k-support-male-to-male-elements-series-1m.html

Comment: Never heard of that brand, but I have used this [cable](http://amzn.to/2xIcSV5) with good results.  I say this because I have run across seeming good cables that failed spectacularly

Comment: Thanks @Allan Unfortunately  amazon is not available in my region.

Comment: Turns out @IconDaemon and allan  are correct. It is a hardware issue. I purchased another set of cables by a brand called Konix (http://www.auspcmarket.com.au/brands/Konix.html) and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to High Sierra (Version 10.13, build 17A405) allows the monitor to display again.

The picture quality is blurry. It is as if I am using the HDMI input.

It turns out there was issue with the Alogic cable.

At the end I purchased a new set of cables (Konix) and the problem is resolved.